# How to bind a multi-select element with object array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a  element , which I would like to bind with a model to get/set the value and to populate it from a list using angular 1

The way I have it, I am able to bind it from UI to model, not vice versa, what am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select class="form-control"        
    ng-options="o as o.prop for o in brands"  
    ng-model="selectedBrands" 
    multiple="multiple" 
    >
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.brands = [{
    prop: 1
  }, {
    prop: 2
  }, {
    prop: 3
  }];
  $scope.selectedBrands = [{
    prop: 2
  }];
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4L8b7cke/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuse `$scope.brands` elements, do not create new for selected items, because ngModel watches the model by reference.

```
$scope.selectedBrands = [$scope.brands[0],$scope.brands[1]];
```

Update:

> By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is important to know when binding the select to a model that is an object or a collection.

From [ngOptions documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks!

Comment: I will accept this answer in ten min (SO wont let me do it right now)

Comment: @Matej: for those of us not familiar with Angular (and I include myself in that list) can you explain what the problem was, why it was a problem and how this answer solves that problem? (I accept that "it's magic" might well be the explanation, however.)

Comment: From my knowledge i don't find a problem in the question. Could you please explain what was the thing in the question that made you suggest 
$scope.selectedBrands = [$scope.brands[0],$scope.brands[1]];
as an answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas I assumed that Angular binds by reference rather than checking equality on the values being set in the controller with the list possible values.

Comment: From the JSFiddle @SajjanSarkar has posted. I don't find any issues there.

Comment: I agree with @DavidThomas

Comment: @AKA Does my explanation hold?

Comment: What was your problem here? @SajjanSarkar

Comment: I can see the multiple select dropdown working properly from UI to model and vice versa. Where you found the problem?

Comment: check the fiddle. when setting the value from the controller, it wasnt setting it in the UI

Comment: You should see here. https://www.screencast.com/t/KcJXbkGlzc8
I am able to select multiple values and the model is reflected with the selected values.

Comment: @AKA please read what I wrote. "when setting the value from the controller, it wasnt setting it in the UI "

Comment: If you know english read your question again. You have mentioned "The way I have it, I am able to bind it from UI to model, not vice versa, what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: which means your value is not binded from model to UI which is working properly in jsfiddle, So the actual problem was different that what you mentioned in the question @SajjanSarkar. First, be sure to use proper words so that people can understand.

Comment: There is no where in the question that says, "when setting the value from the controller, it wasnt setting it in the UI" @SajjanSarkar

Comment: Added explaination why ng-model was not selecting item in UI